# how to print list of tuples in where clause in sql

Tags: python, sql, list, tuples

```
name :[('Sam',),('Bob',),('Claire',),]
Expected Output : select * from table where name in ('Sam','Bob','Claire');
```

I did below which works but I was wondering if I can do it more efficiently

`'(%s)' % ', '.join(map(repr, [row[0] for row in name]))`

this gives me the output as : ('Sam','Bob','Claire')

or can I do this formatting in sql while querying

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQLite, MySQL, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to handle different cases and use `f-string`.

```py
def create_query(name):
    tpl = tuple(n[0] for n in name)
    if len(name) > 1:
        query = f"select * from table where name in {tpl}"
    elif len(name) == 1:
        query = f"select * from table where name = {tpl[0]}"
    else:
        raise ValueError("name is empty")
    return query


name = [
    ("Sam",),
    ("Bob",),
    ("Claire",),
]
query = create_query(name)
print(query)
```

Output:

```
select * from table where name in ('Sam', 'Bob', 'Claire')
```

Comment: problem with this is when name has a single element like```name =[("Sam",),]``` it outputs as ```select * from table where name in ('Sam',)``` and it fails because of the comma at the end.